# Is there a way to add variants to a mini panel?

Tags: panels

I am trying to organize my content as follows, but I am not certain if it is proper to use variants (if there are variants for mini panels) this way.  Suppose I have a page A.  I would like to easily re-use A as a block in other pages, say as a block with a portion of the content of A and a *read more* link and placed in a sidebar of the front page.  Note that I want to do this for a few hand-selected pages, and I hope these blocks can be moved around easily like panes.  So I was thinking if I can do the content of A in a mini-panel A', and use A' in both A and the front page.  But that way I must have two ways to render the mini-panel A'.  So how do I add variants to A'?

Comment: How are you create the page in the first place? Is it a panel page a view page or simply a node?

Comment: They will be panel pages, and the site uses panels a lot, so I tend to look for a panels-solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minipanels don't support variants, however, you can achieve a similar result by adding visibility rules to show/hide minipanel panes on certain pages, according to specified conditions.

Though more simple options are possible, an example using PHP for a visibility check is [here](http://drupal.org/node/1320244)

[image: pane visibility rules]
[image: pane visibility rule options]